# Escaping a character included in a conceal command vimscript

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, viml

I'm playing with conceal in help files to highlight / colour specific text strings. This was working fine until I added the :print: example below.

conceal example

Using this concealed all the : as expected so I tried to escape the : around the word print:

```
:%s/[^[:print:]]//g :
```

The original conceal statement was:

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /[:#]|[#:]/ contained conceal -Oopswrong original
syn match myhelpCommentHc       "[:#]\s.\{-}\s[:#]\s" contains=myIgnoreHc
```

I changed the match to:

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /[:#]\s\S\|\S\s[#:]/ contained conceal
```

which worked if I wrote the `:print:` as `: :print :`

However I'd prefer to escape or tell the parser to ignore the match in certain situations e.g. `::` or `##` as the `:print :` isn't what I was after :).

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I am using the following to hide the opening and closing elements of the match, see image

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /[:#]\s\S\|\S\s[#:]/ contained conceal 
syn match myhelpCommentHc       "[:#]\s.\{-}\s[:#]\s" contains=myIgnoreHc
```

The `: /if line..` example in image does what I want

However if I have a string like

```
: %s/[[:print:]]//g :
```

ie second image , then all `:` are hidden, as expected.

I'm looking for a way to escape the second and third `:` so they aren't hidden without having to write `: %s/[:print:]//g :` in the help file like .

```
: %s/[: :print: :]//g :
```

in order to achieve the second example

[image]

As a workaround I've changed the match command to be

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /\^\*\s\|\s\^\*\s/ contained conceal 
syn match myhelpCommentHc   "\^\*\s.*\s\^\*\s" contains=myIgnoreHc
```

which works until I write help with a second ^* string

[image]

Any suggestions?

Note: This post is a copy of the following as I couldn't get an answer there: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/escaping-a-character-included-in-a-conceal-command-vimscript.

Comment: Already from your question at vi.stackexchange, I don't know what your problem is and what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Please correct the image tag, which was ok in the original post

Comment: I'd have accepted the edit if I knew how :( I'll update what I'm trying to achieve to clarify.